# My Windows 10 does not open some websites

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

I have win 10 on my laptop. Surprisingly, it is 2 months that I can not open some of the websites on my laptop with any browser (Chrome, IE, Firefox, ...), especially the website of universities, even if I type the IP address of the website.

The problem is not form my internet provider because I can load those websites from my mobile via my WiFi (Not my sim-card's internet). Also I can open the websites from Ubuntu inside of a virtual box in my windows. The problem is not from firewall because I disable that and I had the problem again.

I think 2 possibilities may happen.

1- My laptop have some kind of virus, and it prevent visiting universities websites.

2- The windows can not find the DNS server for those websites. When I type ping www.the_intended_website.com it shows the correct IP address for those websites but the response failed because of timeout.

Any suggestion for solving this problem is appreciated.

Comment: The dns server used by the router could be having issues that would heal after a day or so. How long has this been going on?

Comment: @Moab It is more than 2 months.

But it is not related to router. Because if it was related to the router why I can connect to those websites when I use other devices with same router.

Comment: Doesn't read like a DNS issue.  If that was the case, your computer wouldn't be able to translate the domain name to the IP address.

What errors do you get when you try to load the websites that are giving you issues?  You see a 404 page, no internet warning, or something else?

Comment: @ServiceManager In the browsers no internet warning. I used ping command and my windows can translate the domain to a correct ip address. When I tried to get the ip address of those websites from some websites like https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html it gives me the same ip as my machine tries to connect and receives time out error.

Comment: So the sites just don't load?  You get no indication of progress, or notification that they could not load?

Pinging gives a timeout error?  Only for those sites, correct?

Comment: @ServiceManager All are correct. Here is what chrome shows for uni-bonn.de "This site can’t provide a secure connection www.uni-bonn.de sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

Comment: @MahdiJaberzadeh Make sure your clock is set correctly, particularly your year.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It is correct. I strongly think it is a virus. because inside of my virtual Linux I can open those websites but not in the host operating system which is windows 10.

Comment: Disabling ipv6 in WiFi properties solved a similar issue for me

Comment: I looked at the certificate that is served by uni-bonn.de. Nothing out of the ordinary, also the negotiated cipher suite is normal. You said that time and date is correct. Have you messed with the trust store recently? (OS or browser) I virus is highly unlikely. What would blocking access to one universities websites achive?

Answer (score 4):

I found [this guide](https://usefulpcguide.com/16820/fix-err_ssl_protocol_error-google-chrome/) that covers this problem. It does say that this is for Google Chrome, but the majority of these solutions will work on any browser on your computer.

The basics are these:

- Make sure the time and date is correct on your computer
- Try temporarily disabling your antivirus to se if that works better
- Check your `hosts` file for any incorrect information
- Clear the SSL State (`Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Content -> Clear SSL State`)
- Change the security and privacy level for Internet (`Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Security`) to medium

This last one will affect just Google Chrome:

- Disable Chrome QUIC Protocol (go to `chrome://flags/#enable-quic` and select `Disabled` from the drop-down list under QUIC Protocol)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use a public DNS such as google 8.8.8.8 or even try to open a VPN as hotspot shield and test it just to make sure it's not a connectivity issue and you can always check you host file but it's super unlikely to be modified by itself to block the websites you're trying to reach .